# ajax value not returned

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function validateEmail(){
    var check =email();
    alert(check);    
}
function email()
{
    var TCode = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var result="hey";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "get_email.jsp",
        data: "email="+TCode,
        success: function(html){
            $("#email_info").html(html);
            result=$("#email_info").html(html);
            return result;
        }
    });
}
```

get_email.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="bean.*" %>
<%@ page import="database.*" %>


<%  

                                                int flag=0;
                                                String Email=request.getParameter("email");
                                                userDAO UD=new userDAO();
                                                flag=UD.getEmailInfo(Email);
                                                if(flag==1)
                                                {
                                                    %>
                                                 Available
                                                <% }
                                                else
                                                {%>Not Available
                                            <%}%>
```

NOTE: MY AJAX FUNCTION IS SYNCHRONOUS

now from function validate email i am calling a function email where i call a jsp page and there i check if the email in database already exist or not from there i return text which is displayed on my page but what i want is that i get some value from this ajax function as well that if email id already exist it should not let user to submit form but i am unable to get value in validate email function ...it gives me undefined value.

Comment: please post your server-side code

Comment: Move the `return result;` out of the callback.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat ...where should i put it then?

Comment: @RocketHazmat after ajax function or success function?

Comment: @user2137186: After `$.ajax`, you can't put it after `success` that makes no sense.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it alerts [object,object now]

Comment: @user2137186: That's because it's not a string.  `alert` is not a good debugging tool.  Try to `console.log` instead.

Comment: @user2137186: You're doing `result=$("#email_info").html(html);`.  That sets `result` to a jQuery object!  Just do `result = html;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add one callback, even that you are using sync request the return function will be undefined.

```
function validateEmail(){
    email(function(check){
        alert(check)
    });
}
function email(callback)
{
    var TCode = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var result="hey";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "get_email.jsp",
        data: "email="+TCode,
        success: function(html){
            $("#email_info").html(html);
            result=$("#email_info").html(html);
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it alerts [object,object now]

Comment: do result=html instead of result=$("#email_info").html(html); in the success function

Answer (score 1):

Put all of your post-ajax processing in the `success` callback.

Comment: He set async: false, so it should be synchronous

Comment: Well I'll be damned... you're right. I never even considered that'd be an option, given the name of the function! Callback answer stands, I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Returning from the `success` function does nothing.  That doesn't magically make `email` return a value.

You need to make `email` return the value, by moving the `return` outside of the callback.

```
function email()
{
    var TCode = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var result="hey";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "get_email.jsp",
        data: "email="+TCode,
        success: function(html){
            $("#email_info").html(html);
            result = html;  // Don't set this to a jQuery object
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

This will work, but I ***highly*** suggest NOT doing it this way!!  `async: false` will make the browser lock up and not respond to any input until the AJAX request is done.

What you should do is lose the `async: false`, and use callbacks.  Note, you may need to change your program logic.  You're not supposed to return from AJAX calls.

```
function validateEmail(){
    email(function(check){
        console.log(check);
    });
}
function email()
{
    var TCode = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var result="hey";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "get_email.jsp",
        data: "email="+TCode,
        success: function(html){
            $("#email_info").html(html);

            if(typeof callback === 'function'){
                callback(html);
            }
        }
    });
}
```